# Portions of test "run as localadministrator"

Tags: c#, windows, security

I am developing some tests for Redis servers. Each of these servers run as Windows services. I have three sentinels monitoring one master with one slave. The sentinels are responsible for the failover of the master (essentially conerting the slave to a master). As part of my test I would like to simulate a master failing by stopping the service. I get an array of ServiceController instances and specifically I get a ServiceController instance that corresponds to the master service. The problem is that when I call the method Stop on the ServiceController instance I get an InvalidOperationException because I do not have sufficient permission to stop the service.

I have a domain account in the corporate domain. This domain account is in the local administrators group so I have permission to stop the service. If I run VS (devenv.exe) as Administrator ("Run as Administrator") the whole test runs just fine. But I would rather that the whole test not run as administrator and it makes explaining how to run these tests difficult when I have to explain that VS needs to run as administrator. I want just the portion of the test (stopping the service) only to run as administrator. The rest of the test can be run as the logged on user (me). I cannot use the Win32 LogonUser because I don't have the local Administrators credentials and many of the "built-in" accounts like local administrator don't have a password. So what I want is some way to impersonate the local administrator (essentially programmatically doing a "run-as administrator"). Again this is a unit test so I cannot use the oft proposed answers by spawning a new process. I want something similar to Impersonate where I can impersonate, do some work, and revert.  Ideas?

Comment: you hit on the key word as to what you will need to do and that is setup the service to run as `impersonation` in the .config file.. I would totally not recommend this but if it's just for testing .. it should not hurt.. if you have not used `impersonation` google it there are many examples

Comment: You can't do that because the security system was designed not to allow that (bugs that allow this notwithstanding). If that was possible then a malicious program could easily obtain administrator privileges. Honestly, running VS as admin is really the easiest way. Just do a check for admin rights before starting the test and fail with a clear message saying "Admin rights required, restart VS with 'run as administrator'." The other alternative is to spawn another process that requests elevation, just keep it running so the user doesn't have to click some dialog every test run.

Comment: Also this is obviously not a "unit test" if it requires starting and stopping services.